# Horizontal divider of the StatusStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, statusstrip

In a `Windows.Forms` application, I want to change the color of the horizontal divider line of the `StatusStrip`, or make this line invisible. Any ideas?

This is the I'm referring to:

[image]

**file: Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test {
    class Program {

        [STAThread]

        static void Main() {
            Application.Run(new FormMain());
        }
    }
}
```

**file: FormMain.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test {
    class Vars {
        public class Colors {
            public static Color BackRed = Color.FromArgb(040, 000, 000);
            public static Color ForeRed = Color.FromArgb(240, 120, 120);
            public static Color BackGrn = Color.FromArgb(000, 040, 000);
            public static Color ForeGrn = Color.FromArgb(120, 240, 120);
            public static Color BackBlu = Color.FromArgb(000, 000, 040);
            public static Color ForeBlu = Color.FromArgb(120, 120, 240);
        }
    }

    class FormMain : Form {
        MenuStrip menuStrip = new MenuStrip();
        StatusStrip statusStrip = new StatusStrip();

        public FormMain() {
            this.FormMain_Setup();
        }

        private void FormMain_Setup() {
            this.Top = 20;
            this.Left = 20;
            this.Width = 1200;
            this.Height = 675;
            this.BackColor = Vars.Colors.BackBlu;
            this.ForeColor = Vars.Colors.ForeBlu;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.KeyDown += FormMain_KeyDown;
            this.FormMain_MenuStrip_Setup();
            this.FormMain_StatusStrip_Setup();
        }

        private void FormMain_StatusStrip_Setup() {
            this.statusStrip.Height = 30;
            this.statusStrip.AutoSize = false;
            this.statusStrip.BackColor = Vars.Colors.BackRed;
            this.statusStrip.ForeColor = Vars.Colors.ForeRed;
            this.statusStrip.SizingGrip = false;
            this.Controls.Add(statusStrip);
        }

        private void FormMain_MenuStrip_Setup() {
            this.menuStrip.Height = 30;
            this.menuStrip.AutoSize = false;
            this.menuStrip.BackColor = Vars.Colors.ForeGrn;
            this.menuStrip.ForeColor = Vars.Colors.BackGrn;
            this.Controls.Add(menuStrip);
        }

        private void FormMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            this.FormMain_Exit();
        }

        private void FormMain_Exit() {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yegods your application looks ugly. Please tell me these are testing colors or at least that your client has a gun to your end.

Comment: Well, (1) I don't think that this question is off the topic. There may be a `Windows.Forms` property that changes the color of the line I'm referring to and it's what I'm searching for. (2) The colors used are what the customer preferred (dark colors).

Comment: I don't think that divider is coming from the StatusStrip.  Just a plain form with a dark blue backcolor and a StatusStrip with a backcolor of brown produced no divider line.  Is the dark blue a panel?  Are you using a TableLayoutPanel?  Post the *minimal* designer code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: All the code lines has been added at the end of the "question" part (above).

Comment: The code you posted does not duplicate the line.  I get a clean transition from brown to blue.

Comment: Is it the Windows version that makes the difference? Mine is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I add `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` into `Main()` that problem line disappeared.

```
namespace test {
    class Program {

        [STAThread]

        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles(); // this line added
            Application.Run(new FormMain());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this 6+ years old question while I was googling around. I don't think it remains a problem for the OP. Just for the future readers.

---

When you add a `StatusStrip` instance by the designer or code, you will see a thin horizontal line over the top of the control.

[image: SOQ28492071A]

You can get rid of this line by explicitly set the `StatusStrip.BackColor` property to any color. In the designer, change the color to anything and set it back to the inherited one (the Form's) and it will disappear. Alternatively, in code, set the property to itself:

```cs
private void FormMain_StatusStrip_Setup()
{
    this.statusStrip.BackColor = this.statusStrip.BackColor;
    //...
}
```

[image: SOQ28492071B]

See [Winforms ToolStrip.BackColor returns wrong color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594382/winforms-toolstrip-backcolor-returns-wrong-color) for more details about this behavior.

---

In your case, obviously the `BackColor` trick has no effect, the line remains as we can see in your image. This could be a result of a custom [`ToolStripRenderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer?view=netframework-4.8) if you have one assigned to the [`StatusStrip.Renderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.renderer?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_ToolStrip_Renderer) property which uses the default values and ways to render the strips including the borders.

Consider this example:

```cs
public class FormMain
{
    public FormMain() : base()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.statusStrip.Renderer = new MyCustomRenderer();
    }
}

public class MyCustomRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public MyCustomRenderer() : base(new MyColorTable()) { }
}

public class MyColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color StatusStripGradientBegin => Color.Black;
    public override Color StatusStripGradientEnd => Color.Black;
    // ...
}
```

[image: SOQ28492071C]

Here, you need to override the renderer's [`OnRenderToolStripBorder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer.onrendertoolstripborder?view=net-5.0) method to prevent drawing the border of the `StatusStrip`.

```cs
public class MyCustomRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public MyCustomRenderer() : base(new MyColorTable()) { }

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.ToolStrip is StatusStrip)) base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
    }
}
```

[image: SOQ28492071D]

Or maybe to draw the line with a color of your choice:

```cs
protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ToolStrip is StatusStrip)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, 0, e.ToolStrip.Width, 0);
    else
        base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
}
```

[image: SOQ28492071E]