# Change border of Statusbar to match Toolbar border

Tags: c#, winforms

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR0VP.png)

See the image. The default border or Windows forms statusbar is different from the on Windows forms toolbar use and I want them to match. How can I change the border color of preferably the statusbar?

I have tried to google and play with the appearance but have not succeded.
I found StatusbarAdvanced but it is not available for me and I look for a clean and simple solution. Should be something like Appearance.Border.BorderColor or something like that in my opinion...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492071/horizontal-divider-of-the-statusstrip/68416461#68416461